Using AnimatedSwticher in a changing Column layout
When using AnimatedSwitcher inside a Column like so it works fine:
Column(
  children: [
    AnimatedSwitcher(...),
    // Some other stuff
  ]
)

But if I change the layout of the column during the rebuild, it doesn't do the animation anymore Ig because the structure of its subtree changed so it thinks its a new widget
Column(
  children: [
    // Some other stuff
    AnimatedSwitcher(...),
  ]
)

Any workaround or fix to this?

in AnimatedSwitcher child property are you passing a ValueKey like this?
AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
              return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
            },
            child: Text(
              '$_count',
              // This key causes the AnimatedSwitcher to interpret this as a "new"                  
              // when the count changes.
              key: ValueKey<int>(_count),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ),

If this is not enough, can you share the full code please?

Yes I am using keys. I will create a minimal example and notify you
